# Path [DEST] Ansible COPY

Tags: ansible

estoy intentando crear un playbook para mandar un documento desde el servidor (local) a diferentes ordenadores (remoto), el problema que tengo es que cada ordenador tiene un usuario distinto, y desde el playbook no se como identificar el nombre de esos usuarios.

la tarea de mi playbook se ve así:

```
tasks:
- name: Copiar fichero de local a remoto
        copy:
          src: /files/README.txt [Esto está OK]
          dest: Users/*Aquí debería ir el nombre o variable/wildcard del usuario */Desktop/README.TXT [El problema es aquí]
```

He intentado con /Users/*/Desktop
pero no me funciona, alguien sabe alguna manera de hacerlo? gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te comparto una posible manera de solucionarlo.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Como me dices que no sabes cual es ese nombre de carpeta, tú has comentado la opción de `awk`. Yo en tu caso lo tiraría con el comando `find`y la ruta que devolviera usarla como ruta para copiar:

```
- name: "Varias acciones"
  hosts: server
  tasks:
    - name: Encontrar la ruta
      shell: find Users -type d -name "Desktop"
      register: path
    - name: Copiar fichero de local a remoto
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: /files/README.txt
        dest: "{{path.stdout}}/README.TXT"
```

**COMENTARIO ANTIGUO**

Puedes poner el nombre de la carpeta relacionada con cada servidor como variable en tu archivo "inventory". Un ejemplo sería algo así:

**inventory_test**

```
[server_1]
12.12.12.12

[server_2]
14.14.14.14

[server:children]
server_1
server_2

[server_1:vars]
carpeta=pedro

[server_2:vars]
carpeta=juan
```

Le pones la IP que corresponda a cada servidor, luego todos los servidores los englobas en `server` con `server:children`, y a cada servidor por separado le pones la variable `carpeta` que será el nombre que usarás al copiar.

Y teniendo un playbook de este estilo:

**playbook_test.yml**

```
- name: "Varias acciones"
  hosts: server
  tasks:
    - name: Copiar fichero de local a remoto
      ansible.builtin.copy:
        src: /files/README.txt
        dest: Users/{{carpeta}}/Desktop/README.TXT
```

Aunque el uso de `copy` es correcto, en la documentación de Ansible recomiendan el uso de [ansible.builtin.copy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) para evitar posibles conflictos. Y poniendo la variable `{{carpeta}}` en el destino añadirá en el usuario de cada servidor.

Por último, para ejecutarlo sería algo como esto (no he usado ni estructura de carpetas para los archivos ni nada, eso como lo tengas tú estructurado):

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory_test playbook_test.yml
```

Espero que te pueda servir

Comment: Hola @msalinas, eso funcionaría pero para usuarios esperados, pero no tengo forma de saber si en tal equipo se sentará [Pepe, Juan ó María] por eso quería tirar por wildcards, he intentado lanzar antes una tarea que sea shell: w, y parsear con awk el usuario activo, cogerlo en una variable y luego ponerlo en la siguiente task que es el copy, de todas formas muchas gracias :)

Comment: @abello-r, perdona que pensaba que sí tenías acceso al nombre de la carpeta. Creo que `copy` no tiene la posibilidad de poner wildcards, pero por si te sirve, he añadido una posibilidad de cómo podrías conseguir esa ruta. Creo que es algo más sencilla que lo que proponías de parsear con `awk`

Comment: Eso viene genial también, muchísimas gracias :)

Comment: De nada! Me alegra que te pueda servir 